# XPath to return always null

Tags: xml, xpath

How make an XPath that always return a  `null` node list ?

I am not an XPath expert, I could work out `*[not(node())]`. Is it okay ?

--

I need it because I have two methods : one builds an XPath, and the other is looking for the matches. For some particular cases I want to force a `null` result depending on the input of the first method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How make an XPath that always return a  null node list ?

Simple.

```
/*[false()]
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest is:

XPath 1.0: `/..`

XPath 2.0: `()`